# Get logged fb user but NOT authorised the app (outside of canvas page)

Tags: facebook

Alright, looking at the JS SDK there is this:

```
auth.statusChange
```

> Typically you will want to use the auth.sessionChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:
>
> - Connected
> - Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
> - Not logged into Facebook at all.

So I would be using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    // do something with response
    console.log (response)
});
```

You'd have thought this is exactly what I need, but guess what.  Even if I satisfy the condition :

> - Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application

I'm still getting session = null!

Can anyone please suggest a way of getting the session of a logged in user but hasn't yet approved the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't get session unless the user approved your app.

You can use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus to see if user logged in, but not connected.

> "The status of the User. One of connected, notConnected or unknown".

Comment: But what I want to do is ultimately get the userid of the connected user.  I have used this before and all it gives me is status: not connected, although I am connected into FB in another tab.

Comment: notConnected => user is logged in Facebook, but not connected to your app. I am about 80% sure you can't get userid with js sdk if the user did not authorize your app.

Comment: thanks for replying, I kinda figured this was the case.  its a shame thought as I thought I recalled that you were able to determine which fb user was connected.